# DataGridView paging

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have applications(WinForm) that gets some objects from webservice. After receiving array I transform array to DataTable and show data in DataGridView. Problem is when there are too many records. Of course I can change WS to send information in packages containing for example 100 objects but I'm not sure how to change DataGridView. Could you please provide some example?

Thanks

Comment: Here's a [simple working example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825771/how-can-we-do-paging-in-datagridview-in-winform/9504739#9504739).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be easy to do .
Just edit the properties of the datagrid in designview(little arrow at the right) and enable it. Have a look at [this aticle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx)

Comment: As I can see it's only for ASP and I'm developing winforms application

Comment: Sorry, should have read more carefully ---
Seems there is a programmatical way - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DataGridBoundedPaging.aspx
and there is a codeplex project (not shure bout paging in this) - http://www.codeplex.com/sourcegrid/

Answer (score 0):

I think so far [bindingSource control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/Pagable_DatagridView.aspx) provides the best solution .