# paging techniques for datagridview using in winforms applications

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I am looking for paging techniques for datagird view used in winforms applications...

For this i have looked around the google but dint find any options for winforms datagrdiview but i have found the solutions for web apps..

would any one pls give any idea or any source code for how to implement the paging techniques for datagrid view ...

I am using linq ,for getting the data from database..   I am using linq and mysql as database.. and i am binding the datagrid view using linq to entities....

so if there are any techniques for linq to implement the paging techniques for datagrid view.. will be help ful to me ...

Thanks In advance for greatful ideas...

Comment: Here's a [simple working example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825771/how-can-we-do-paging-in-datagridview-in-winform/9504739#9504739).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried to check if Google works correctly :)

[Paging in DataGrid Winforms](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/3c50bb9b-3eea-4fa9-a932-1673dea5cd8a/)

[How to paging a datagridview in winform?](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/7/10070170/how-to-paging-a-datagridview-in-winform.aspx)

[A Simple Way for Paging in DataGridView in WinForm Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/TipsnTricks/PagingInDataGridView.aspx)

Hope this articles will be helpful for you.

Comment: Many Thanks ....those all are implemented with sql server but I am using linq and mysql as  database.. and i am binding the datagrid view using linq to entities..would you pls suggest any ideas around this.....

Comment: [LINQ to SQL (Part 3 - Querying our Database)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/29/linq-to-sql-part-3-querying-our-database.aspx) by Scott Gu. For taking the necessary entities for page it's used `.Skip()` and `.Take()`

Answer (score 0):

As you writing Windows Form application that reads a data from MySQL, it's not good decision IMHO to implement a paging in DataGrid view. Basically you have to transfer on wire as small amount of data as you can.

So I would, personally, use a `LIMIT` MySQL command to page on DB side, and after load the data to my app. You can always load 2,3 pages but show to user one, for faster and fluid  GoForward/GoBack navigation between pages (preload data in short), but it's something that it's difficult to consider to me if it's a good solution or not as I don't know your project requirements.

For local paging you can simply split an array of rows you receive in subgroups and visualize one group per time.

Hope this helps.