# C# monitoring changes of a T-SQL table in a DGV

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is my situation:

- Several services and a GUI log their informations, error messages
  etc. to a T-SQL table.
- A GUI is running where the last entries of this table are shown in a
  DGV.
- I am using a `DataTable` filled with T-SQL table entries and bound to
  the DGV.
- I am checking for new entries by comparing the creation time of the
  last shown entry with the maximum creation time found in the T-SQL
  table.

Is there a mechanism to update the `DataTable` and of course the bound DGV without filling the complete `DataTable` every time I detect new entries in the T-SQL table?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a use case for [RX](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/02_KeyTypes.html).

Comment: And what if someone deletes an entry or changes its status or details?

Comment: Detecting database table changes is possible by triggers on delete, insert, update. But it is not clear you want to detect changes or need to update DGV?

Comment: Could you use SqlMonitor class?

Comment: Take a look here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/537649/SQL-Server-Change-Tracking-CT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplest custom way is to add a trigger to your table that will generate new GUID if the data have been changed and save this GUID in a new table. (Try this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx)

You can do it for all tables.

So you have to periodically get this value and match it with an old one. 
If they are different then get full set of data. ([Better if you will use the paging mechanism.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298450/paging-techniques-for-datagridview-using-in-winforms-applications))

Your situation in fact could be described like "**How to Detect Table Changes or Changes in Data**"  so take a look here as well http://sqlserverplanet.com/design/how-to-detect-table-changes