# gridview search and paging in C#

Tags: c#

how can I search in a gridview and just show the result with paging in it instead of whole data in gridview?

I wrote this code to search:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Reserve_dataGridView.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells["Cardserial"].Value.ToString().Equals(textBox1.Text))
            {
                Reserve_dataGridView.Rows[row.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
```

Comment: Is this Winforms or ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [simple answer by Rick Mohr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9504739/612717) on how to do this using [BindingNavigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zhc8d2f%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

You may also want to look at some other articles/implementations on CodeProject.

- [DataGridView With Paging Step by Step](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/446472/Step-by-Step-Creating-UserControl-DataGridView-Wit)
- [Paging in DataGridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19241/Paging-in-a-DatagridView)
- [A simple way for Paging in DataGridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/211551/A-Simple-way-for-Paging-in-DataGridView-in-WinForm)
- [DataGrid Paging](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16303/DataGrid-Paging-C-Windows-Forms)