# BindingNavigator with DataGridView for Paging function?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingnavigator

Guys I am trying to implement paging in my datagridview through bindingnavigator in C# windows forms application.

I have simply dragged datagridview and bindingnavigator from Toolbar to form. Datagridview is databounded to a database table in SQL server using dataset. I have added 3 extra buttons to gridview that will be doing some function.

Now I have never used bindingnavigator before, so I just selected bindingsource of datagridview1 for datasource of bindingnavigator from its properties.

This is how my form looks upon running :

[image]

Currently, datagridview1 displays all the records in my table (31, as of now) and binding navigator next button just takes me to next record (for example, from TicketID=1 to TicketID=2).

Now, what I want to do is :

1.) Datagridview should only display 10(or 50) records per page, and bindingnavigator control should be used to switch between pages so that the UI remains responsive and it becomes more "memory-efficient" because eventually my database will have thousands of records.

2.) BindingNavigator's controls should appear in center of the form, not to the left/right. I couldn't set it to center from properties.

Code behind my form :

```
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.ComponentModel;
       using System.Data;
       using System.Drawing;
       using System.Linq;
       using System.Text;
       using System.Threading.Tasks;
       using System.Windows.Forms;

       namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
       {
           public partial class Form9 : Form
           {
               public Form9()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form9_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CenterToScreen();
        try
        {
            this.tblTicketDetailTableAdapter.Fill(this.sTDataSet4.tblTicketDetail);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : Cannot establish a valid connection to database.", "SQL SERVER ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Detail"].Index)
        {
            //some code
        }
        else if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Close"].Index)
        {
            //some code
        }
        else if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["ViewDetail"].Index)
        {
            //some code
        }
    }

}
```

Now what can I do to make `bindingnavigator` work as paging control?

Comment: check the answer of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825771/how-can-we-do-pagination-in-datagridview-in-winform) SO question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do this is by breaking up the parent table into a list of DataTables (or my preference, `BindingList<DataTable>`) and then assigning the grid's DataSource on the position change of the navigator control:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
BindingList<DataTable> tables = new BindingList<DataTable>();

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnLoad(e);

  int counter = 0;
  DataTable dt = null;
  foreach (DataRow dr in tblTicketDetail.Rows) {
    if (counter == 0) {
      dt = tblTicketDetail.Clone();
      tables.Add(dt);
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
    ++counter;
    if (counter > 9) {
      counter = 0;
    }
  }
  bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bs;
  bs.DataSource = tables;
  bs.PositionChanged += bs_PositionChanged;
  bs_PositionChanged(bs, EventArgs.Empty);
}

void bs_PositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dataGridView1.DataSource = tables[bs.Position];
}
```

As far as centering the BindingNavigator control, just set the Dock style to None and position the control in the center manually.  Once set, set the Anchors to none and the ToolBar should "float" in the center when the container is resized.

Comment: Wow, so simple! For paging in a dgv, Microsoft has Virtual Mode, which seemed pretty complicated when I read about it.

Comment: @LarsTech Say you have 2 pages of data in your DataGridView and you change the date of one item on the second page to have a date earlier than any items on the first or second pages, then sort the DataGridView by the date column. I want the item to then appear first on the first page, but it's only showing up as the first item on the second page which would be the second DataTable. I'm not sure how to do this, but I think after a sort I would need to somehow recalculate the items in each DataTable and refresh the DataGridView to show the updated contents of the DataTables.

Comment: @Rich Nothing built in, so you either move the row item manually yourself to the correct location, or re-paginate all the pages again.