# vb.net display sql server query results in table and display 20 records every time

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I am using vb.net to query sql server database, after querying I want to display the results in table with 20 records a page, and there should have  "backward" and "forward" button to allow user to look other pages of records.

Can this realized by using DataGridView? I haven't found a solution for it. Thanks.

Comment: how you filling your `DataGridView` using datasource or what ??, show your code also

Comment: Hi hector, I just start thinking a solution for it (so not coding yet), not sure what should I use to export the query results and display in a table. Any suggestion?

Comment: This is all you'll need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825771/how-can-we-do-pagination-in-datagridview-in-winform . Next time please do a google search...

Comment: Hi N55PEC, thanks for the link, although it use c#, I will follow the workflow.