# Binding DataGridView in windows forms to a list<List<T>>

Tags: windows, forms, datagridview, paging

I have a collection of custom objects in format List of List of T , i.e, a List Of list of custom objects.
I need to bind this collection to a datagridview control in windows forms, and the number of pages should be equal to the number of inner lists in the outer list. Each page should bind to inner List, that is,  List of T.
Any idea how this can be achieved ?

Comment: What you mean when sad "pages" of datagridview?

Comment: Since the original collection is a list of lists, i would like to do Paging based on the inner lists. so the number of pages in the grid would be equal to the number of inner lists.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825771/how-can-we-do-pagination-in-datagridview-in-winform

Comment: Thanks, thats quite helpful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that your nested list has been populated, and in addition to your `DataGridView`, your form has a `Previous` and `Next` button for changing pages: you could use the buttons to change an index which indicates which nested list is to be used as the `DataSource`.

```
public List<List<MyObject>> Pages { get; set; } // Populated elsewhere...
public int PageIndex { get; set; }

private void ChangePage()
{
  this.PreviousButton.Enabled = this.PageIndex > 0;
  this.NextButton.Enabled = this.PageIndex < this.Pages.Count - 1;
  this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.Pages[this.PageIndex];
}

private void PreviousButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.PageIndex--;
  this.ChangePage();
}

private void NextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.PageIndex++;
  this.ChangePage();
}
```