# How to add next and previous buttons in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Hi can I ask help on how to add next and previous button to navigate records in datagridview. In datagridview, I want to display at least 15 records in the first page and then another 15 in the next page. Unfortunately, I  never tried anything yet because I dont have any idea on how to do it. So your ideas or suggestions would be a great help for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI you can have a scrollable datagridview

Comment: You can control the FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex property to set the row that is at the top of the dgv. This would in effect allow you to page up and down if that's what you're meaning. For example, if I were to have a dgv that shows 5 rows at a time and contains 20 rows. I could set FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 5 and this would scroll the dgv to show rows 5 through 9. Keep in mind that the first row is index 0. You would also want to perform some checks to ensure that the index doesn't go below 0 when moving down and doesn't go above the total number of rows when moving up

Comment: Let's say you have all your data in a single list or table - you'd normally source your grid as `dataGridView.DataSource = theListOrTable;`. Instead of this, you could chunk your data into 1. A list of lists of 15 items, or 2. multiple tables of 15 items. Then just use buttons to change your grid data source amongst those lists/table as I've shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29995385/3773066).

Comment: Consider using a DataAdapter where the overloaded Fill method accepts start index and how many rows to populate into the DataTable, combine this with a variables to keep  track of how many rows are loaded and then how many rows to load past this index via buttons. The DataAdapter, DataSet and tracking integer variable would be private level of the form or class working with the data.