# Display 10 rows alternately with the timer in the DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I would like to display the data added to the table in the DataGridView by pulling 10 rows each time with the timer.

Comment: Please expand on what you are trying to achieve exactly and what you have done so far. I guess you want to do something akin to paging in a gridview: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825771/how-can-we-do-pagination-in-datagridview-in-winform

Comment: Thank you for the answer..
It does not look like no paging.
First of all, I keep datetime datatypes in the database.
I want to draw ten data from the database every second for the DataGridView table, which is equal to the current time and date.