# Datagridview - Quicker way to populate with List loop?

Tags: c#

Currently, I'm planning to add ~500K List to datagridview.

Class has multiple Fields, Each List has 13 fields.
but i bind only 7 fields for now.

Problem is,it seems like adding takes too much time. like 5sec for 15K which is awful.

Is there any ways to optimze this?
or should i throw away datagridview and consider some other views?

```
    private void UpdateDataGrid()
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < gVar.gTagCount; i++)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[]
            {
                gVar.Tags[i].TagCount,
                gVar.Tags[i].Name,
                gVar.Tags[i].Score.Story,
                gVar.Tags[i].Score.Drawing,
                gVar.Tags[i].Score.Drawing,
                gVar.Tags[i].Score.Memetic,
                gVar.Tags[i].DupeCount
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of doing it like this, i think it would be better to make a class, populate a list of that class and then use the datasource property to populate the datagridview

Comment: @nalnpir i already populated a list of that class, since i export them from raw text file (iterates each lines, add its value to field) / formatted json file.

After that i loops them like this.

Comment: You dont need to use Rows.Add if you already have a populated list. You can simply dataGridView1.Datasource = listofyourclass;

Comment: Use the List as the DataSource, it will be almost instantaneous.  You may have to refactor that class though.

Comment: @nalnpir I forgot to say this, sorry. the reason that im looping like this is Tag class has other fields, not just that ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what we discussed my approach would be this:

First make a new Class, I would call it TagsMin this class should contain the 7 things you want in your datagridview.

Secondly i would populate that a list of that class like this (you need to complete it with what you want):

```
var tagList = gVar.Tags.Select(x => new TagsMin() { TagCount = x.TagCount, Name = x.Name... }).ToList()
```

And the last step, would be to bind it to the datagridview:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = tagList;
```

Comment: Welp, this adds rows but all datas are blank, TagsMin does get a right data so i guess Datasource = TagList needs some additional works?

Comment: show me the way you created the class. Did you use properties?

Comment: nope.    



 public class TagforGrid
    {
        public string Name = null;

        public int DupeCount = 0;
        public int TagCount = 0;
        public int URLCount = 0;
        //picked val is used for Random-Picking percentage value.
        public int PickedCount = 0;

            public int Score_Story = 0;
            public int Score_Reality = 0;
            public int Score_Drawing = 0;
            public int Score_Memetic = 0;

    }

Comment: For this to work you need to have get settings for your public methods, so either you use auto properties (write prop and press tab twice, this is the snippet), or you write a getter for every method you have

Comment: actually that was DataPropertyName problem. i had to set that to same as field name. Thanks for all answers! now its much quicker than before :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using paging so that you are not loading all of the data at once. The answer to the question linked to below provides an example.

[How can we do pagination in datagridview in winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825771/how-can-we-do-pagination-in-datagridview-in-winform)

Comment: This is correct. The GridView will "crash" with so many records, it will be difficult and slow to even scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to avoid the loop and directly bind the list with the standard way:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = gVar.Tags;
```

Comment: No, cause Tags have multiple other Fields. thats why i loop them like that.