# How do I show a “Loading . . . please wait” with gif image message in vb.net for a long loading form?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, loading, wait

vb.net
I have a form(called Form1) that is very slow because it contain datagridview how load data from sql server.As a result the form takes a long time to loaded.
So I create a form_Wait and in the load event of Form1 I put

```
Form_wait.showdialog()
Load_datagridveiw1("Select * from table1")
Form_wait.close()
```

My problem is the Form_Wait will be appear but the gift inside it (rectangular progress bar) is not showen ?
I used VS 2015

Comment: VB.NET has splash screen functionality built in and the splash screen is created and displayed on a secondary thread. That is specifically because the UI thread can't load one form and keep another responsive at the same time. You need to do basically the same thing.

Comment: What is the `Form_wait` form doing? If it has a progress bar, then what is it calculating the progress of? It should be obvious that you need to show what the `Form_wait` is doing. Also, your current posted code does not make sense on the last line… `Form_wait.close()` ? … the form is already closed. When using `Form_wait.ShowDialog()` the code will “stop” at that line until the form is closed. Please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: If it is slow because there is a lot of data, you could consider [How can we do pagination in datagridview in winform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2825771/1115360).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot meaningfully show and animate GIF in a same thread as your UI sits. You would have to use a [BackGroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0), which is basically a separate thread. Then the animation will work smoothly and the UI thread will run fine too. There are plenty of `BackGroundWorker` tutorials on the web.

But a huge warning horn rings reading your words. If it is such a huge amount of data causing the slow loading, I would strongly suggest to reconsider how do you fetch the data. Introducing meaningful **filters** and **pagination** are basic ways to tackle this.